# Title and text paragraph indent

Tags: formatting, boxes, text

I'm trying to reproduce those design decision text boxes. How do I do this? They are indented and numbered. See **Design decision 5** and **Design decision 6** in the attached picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `quote` environment. Actually in my example I created a new anvironment but it is not necessary if not too many quotes like these:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{DDC}
\newenvironment{DesignDecision}[1]
{\refstepcounter{DDC}\begin{quote}{\bfseries Design Decision \theDDC: #1}\par}
{\end{quote}}
\begin{document}
\section{test}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{DesignDecision}{Composite reduction}
\lipsum[1]
\end{DesignDecision}


\lipsum[4]

\begin{DesignDecision}{End-to-end communication}
\lipsum[2]
\end{DesignDecision}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]